# Best way to implement Hierarchical data in SQL Server with multiple parents

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy

How can I implement Hierarchical data where a child has two or more parents?

Something like this

```
Parent ID       Child ID
1               2
1               3
3,2             4
4,1             5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Parent ID       Child ID
1               2
1               3
2               4
3               4
1               5
4               5
```